# Running multiple .NET Core application on same port under IIS Express for development

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, development-environment, iis-express

We are migrating a Webforms application based on .NET framework to .NET Core 5. As a part of the process we have decided to break down the single big app into multiple smaller application. As a first step we want to move the Login feature into a separate .NET Core app. This login app will authenticate users and will issue auth-cookie which will be used by the other apps and the old webforms application as well.

For this auth-cookie sharing to work and for other reasons, I need to get all the web apps running on same port but under different virtual directories. For example

```
http://localhost:5000/      -> This will be the old webforms app
http://localhost:5000/login -> This will be .NET Core login app
http://localhost:5000/admin -> This will be say .NET core admin app
```

I know we can set this up easily in production environment using IIS virtual applications or with azure front door etc. But we want to enable an all local (no internet needed) development setup which is also very easy to get up and running.

Is it possible to configure .NET core and IIS Express to behave like this on a single machine? All our developers use Windows 10 Home/Pro. Nobody has IIS installed on their dev boxes and we prefer to keep it that way.

Comment: Thought about using nginx as a proxy?

Comment: Check the following threads: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008369/iis-express-visual-studio-running-multiple-sites-on-the-same-port) and [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513390/how-to-setup-multiple-apps-with-same-port-and-domain-but-different-paths-in-iise), try to change the applicationhost.config  file, and configure the websites's Virtual Directory.

Comment: @ZhiLv, I looked at these threads and for some reason it doesn't work for me. I get the following error when I do this

-```Config Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ChartImg'```

Basically when when same handlers are being added by both apps since its a single process. Any ideas?

Comment: @GeorgePaoli, I think reverse proxy is probably the best solution. We are leaning towards this. Hopefully we can get a nginx reverse proxy running in a docker container in WSL. This is more closely mimic the production scenario as well since these apps could be hosted on different VM's or app services. Thank you.